# Cannot compile ARToolkit on 64-bit Mac

Tags: macos, artoolkit

I was trying to compile ARToolkit on my 64-bit MacMini but when I run make, it give errors as follows

```
   ./videoInternal.h:38:50: error: unknown type name 'SeqGrabComponent'
   ./video.c:255:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'seqGrab'
   ...
```

I realized that these errors are related to Quicktime Framework on Mac but I have no idea how to fix it. My Mac version is 10.7.5, 64-bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickTime is not and won't ever be 64-bit, it has been superseded by QTKit and AVFoundation. ARToolKit Professional v4.x includes a QTKit video input module (http://www.artoolworks.com). ARToolworks has stated that it is their intention to release parts of ARToolKit v4.x under the GPL soon.